# readarray - split string using IFS delimiter returns empty array

Tags: bash

```
#!/bin/bash
a="2015-05-14 14:55:12.916395602 +0530Ttest_12345"
IFS='T' readarray -t ADDR <<< "$a"
echo "${ADDR[@]:1}"
```

I am trying to split the string `a` into time and name using the delimiter `T`. 
On printing the first element in the result array `ADDR`, it prints an empty string however.

How to convert the string with delimiter into array elements?

Comment: Rather strange way... `echo ${a%T*} ${a#*T}` is enough

Answer (score 1, accepted):

cuonglm's answer is right, you should probably use parameter expansion in that context. However, I though a working example on the use of `IFS` was missing :

```
$ IFS=T read -a ADDR <<<"2015-05-14 14:55:12.916395602 +0530Ttest_12345"
$ echo ${ADDR[0]}
2015-05-14 14:55:12.916395602 +0530
$ echo ${ADDR[1]}
test_12345
```

Answer (score 2):

`readarray` read lines from standard input into array, so you can do something like this:

```
$ a="2015-05-14 14:55:12.916395602 +0530Ttest_12345"
$ readarray -t ADDR <<<"$(tr T '\n'<<<"$a")"
$ printf %s\\n "${ADDR[0]}"
2015-05-14 14:55:12.916395602 +0530
$ printf %s\\n "${ADDR[1]}"
test_12345
```

But you don't need an array at all, you can use [parameter expansion](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_06_02):

```
$ a="2015-05-14 14:55:12.916395602 +0530Ttest_12345"
$ printf %s\\n "${a%T*}"
2015-05-14 14:55:12.916395602 +0530
$ printf %s\\n "${a##*T}"
test_12345
```